# Как запустить react.js приложение без node.js

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner in React.js (make with create-react-app). Please tell me how to make prodaction version which work without server. I tried command: npm build, but if i open build\index.html i see nothink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было добавить `"homepage": "."`, в `package.json`. После этого сборка работает.